# In HTML, how can a div take the remainder of the width if another is explicitly set?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to align two div elements horizontally in an HTML page: one is a navigation menu on the left, set explicitly to 180px wide, and the one on the right is the main page content. Is there a way for the right div to take up the remainder of the width? The code I have so far is below, but places the `section` div below the `nav` div rather than alongside it.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav"> </div>
<div class="section"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.nav {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 180px;
}

div.section {
    float: right:
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 180px;
```

I originally tried setting the `position` for both to `fixed`and `height` to `100%`: this gave the correct layout but had no vertical scrolling! I also tried setting the nav div `float` to `left` which worked when no width was set, but did not fill the remainder of the screen (colours have been omitted for clarity).

I would like to avoid the use of tables, if possible. Also, I appreciate that these two div elements could be replaced with HTML5 `<nav>` and `<section>`.

Comment: Can u pout this in jsfiddle, it will be easy for coding

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to float the menu, and then set 'compensating' padding on the other div.

http://jsfiddle.net/D5qfY/12/

HTML:

```
<nav class="menu"> </nav>
<section class="something"></section>
```

CSS:

```
nav.menu {
float: left;
width: 180px;
background: yellow;
height:400px;
}

section.something {
padding-left: 180px;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
background: red;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-left: 180px;`
This will fit the right div to the remaning screen

http://jsfiddle.net/D5qfY/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/D5qfY/5/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/D5qfY/6/embedded/result/

 **Remove** `embedded/result/` from url to see the code

Comment: What happens when one element is shorter?  http://jsfiddle.net/D5qfY/1/.  That's why the margin is there.

Comment: The OP did not express an interest in a solution that requires JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
div.nav {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
}

div.section {
    float: right:
    width: 90%;
}
```

Sorry, can't help with the others, I don't know nav and section.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to give your elements the behavior of tables.

http://jsfiddle.net/AcMc5/2/

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

nav, section {
    display: table-cell;
}

nav {
    width: 12em;
    background: #CCC;
}

<div class="container">
    <nav>Nav</nav>
    <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</section>
</div>
```

Alternately, you could just not float the element that should take up the remaining width:

http://jsfiddle.net/D5qfY/3/

```
section {
    background: #F00;
    margin-left: /* width of floated sibbling */;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example. This will work for you.

**CSS**

```
    #left {
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 160px;
   border:1px solid #000;
}
#right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
  /*text-align:right;*/
}
```

**Html**

```
<nav id="left">
    Left
</nav>
<section id="right">
    right
</section >
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to float both containers. You can float the nav and let the other container automatically fill the full size of the parent. The *overflow* property can help with positioning and spacing.

```
.nav {
    background: lightgrey;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 180px;           
}

.section {
    background: grey;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You can wrap both inside a parent container to control the width of both containers.

```
.contain {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    border: 1px solid;
    overflow: auto;
}

<div class="contain">
    <div class="nav"> nav </div>
    <div class="section"> section </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define `width: auto;` for your `section`. Alternatively set as this:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

css...

```
div.wrap{background: red; width: 100%;display: inline-block;}
div.nav {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: blue;
}

div.section {
    float: right:
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-lef/t: 180px; /* this need not to place coz you have floated it right*/
}
```

See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymEK9/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use the float/overflow hidden method

HTML:

```
   <nav class="menu">Menu</nav>
    <section class="something">Remainder</section>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    background: yellow;
    height:400px;
}

.something {
    background: red;
    float: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/passionatepaul/YC87B/

Other Methods can be found at http://css-response.com/css-remainder/